# Parameter is not valid Exception

Tags: c#

I am try to upload image from an iPhone using a webservice but I got an Exception like -

> {System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.    at
>   System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, Boolean
>   useEmbeddedColorManagement, Boolean validateImageData)}

in following code

```
string acFolder = Server.MapPath("~/Images/");
string imgname = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString().Replace(" ", "").Replace("AM", "").Replace("PM", "").Replace("/", "").Replace("-", "").Replace(":", "") + ".jpeg";

byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(image.Replace(" ", "+"));
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

// Convert byte[] to Image
ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
System.Drawing.Image image2 = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms,true,true);
image2.Save(acFolder + imgname);
```

I got the exception in this line

```
   System.Drawing.Image image2 = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms,true,true);
```

Comment: What [`ParamName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception.paramname.aspx) is reported in the exception?

Comment: What's the purpose of `image.Replace(" ", "+")`? If it is what I guess - shouldn''t it be `Replace("+", " ")` ? As long as FromStream has validateImageData=true, I guess it is just not a valid image stream...

Comment: There are [similar questions on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=image.fromstream%20Parameter%20is%20not%20valid). Have you [googled](http://tinyurl.com/6lknn8p) first?

Comment: Sidenote (not related to your problem): you could also do something like `string imgname=DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm") + ".jpeg";`, then you do not need all those `.Replace()`s.

Comment: @Tisho thanks to reply, when i replace it then i got
Invalid length for a Base-64 char array.

Comment: Uh, doesn't the error message suggest that the image in question does not include EmbeddedColorManagement information? And you are requring it by specifying true as the second parameter to your function call.  (If that's gamma information, it is optional and can be removed -- but not sure if "EmbeddedColorManagement information"  includes gamma, I'm currently researching for more information in this myself.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that it's an [`ArgumentException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3w1b3114) it's to do with one of the arguments passed to the [`FromStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21zw9ah6.aspx) method.

If you open the second of the two links above you'll see from the documentation that an `ArgumentException` is raised when the stream passed does not represent a valid image format (you can confirm this by checking the exception's [ParamName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception.paramname.aspx) property.

So that means the format of the image that is being uploaded is not supported by the `Image` class.  Either that, or the bytes of the image are being screwed in some way.  That would seem to be supported by your own code - where you replace the '+' with ' ' in the base 64 string.  Base64 is not intended to have spaces in it - take that line of code out.

*Update*

Since you say it doesn't work without it - I'm guessing the data is being passed in a manner where an incoming `'+'` is being interpreted as a space and that's why you're trying to reinstate them.  If sent in a request body this shouldn't happen, so since it is I'm guessing the iPhone app and your server need to use [Modified base64 for URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications) instead.

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply when i code out that line i got
System.FormatException: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array.

Comment: Then the iPhone app is either sending the data incorretly, or something you've done earlier has not correctly identified the correct block of base 64 text from the request.  Am I right in thinking that it's being passed in the query string?  If so you and the iPhone app should use [Modified Base 64 for Urls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications)

Comment: Thanks.. now i got the answer.. the data which i got from iphone was not in base64, and i remove that line from code..it's working fine..thanks :D